# switch output upon submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So I have a form, when the form is filled and submit is pressed, I want the form to be "hidden" away and for a few images to appear.

However, I am currently stuck on "hiding" away the form because I need the form to appear again after the user presses a back button on the page(not on the browser) and I also need the values on the form to be brought forward to that page after submit is pressed.

form:

```
<form id = "step1" onsubmit = "return formcheck()">
                <p>
                    Creator:
                    <select name="creator" id = "creator">
                        <option></option>
                        <option name = "abc" value = "nba">nba</option>
                        <option name = "abc" value = "abc"> oiasfn</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Trip Title:
                    <select name="title" id = "title">
                                            <option></option>
                        <option value = "cba">cbz</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Device:
                    <select name="device" id = "device">
                        <option name = "SN" value = "SN">Samsung Note</option>
                        <option name = "abc" value = "abc"> oiasfn</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    No. of devices:
                    <select id = "deviceno" name = "deviceno">
                        <option></option>
                                            <option value = "1">1</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" value="Next"></input>
                </p>
            </form>
```

javascript function formcheck():

```
function formcheck()
{
    var Ccreator = document.getElementById('creator').value;
    var Ctitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
    var Cdevice = document.getElementById('device').value;
    var Cdeviceno = document.getElementById('deviceno').value;

    if(Ccreator == ""||Ctitle == ""||Cdevice == ""||Cdeviceno == "")
    {
        alert("Form incomplete!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#step1").hide();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried $("#formId").hide() when you want to the form and $("#formId").show() when you want to show the form ?

Comment: yes i have. the form doesnt hide though.

Comment: Can you please give us your code to have a look ?

Comment: try wrapping your form with a `span` or a `div` and hide that one instead.

Comment: @JohnKrommidas It didnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to your html script as the [$(form).hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is not a pure js method, Check the working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RBBte/1/). You can hide the form in javascript by

```
document.getElementById("your form id").style.display="none";
```

and please be noted that if you are returning true form the formcheck() method, the form gets submitted and page will be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is just after validating the form values you are returning 'true'. so the form get submitted and page gets refreshed and then again your file comes to the initial state and form get visible

Comment: if you return 'false' from formcheck() your form will get hidden

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery ui tabs http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ 
or some kind of pagination like this plugin http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: i do not want tabs on my page though.

Comment: you don't need to show the tabs themselves, you can just switch between tabs with a script

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="step1">
            <p>
                Creator:
                <select name="creator" id = "creator">
                    <option></option>
                    <option name = "abc" value = "nba">nba</option>
                    <option name = "abc" value = "abc"> oiasfn</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                Trip Title:
                <select name="title" id = "title">
                                        <option></option>
                    <option value = "cba">cbz</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                Device:
                <select name="device" id = "device">
                    <option name = "SN" value = "SN">Samsung Note</option>
                    <option name = "abc" value = "abc"> oiasfn</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                No. of devices:
                <select id = "deviceno" name = "deviceno">
                    <option></option>
                                        <option value = "1">1</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" value="Next"></input>
            </p>
        </form>
```

jquery:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    return false;
    $('#step1').hide();
    // show anything here.
})
```